# what are the ffmpeg parameters for capturing the screen on raspbian?

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to record the screen produced by my
raspberry pi. I don't need sound.

What I've tried / what I'm seeing:

```
$ ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+100,200 output.mp4
ffmpeg version 5.1.4-0+rpt1+deb12u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+rpt1+deb12u1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --disable-mmal --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sand --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-libjxl --enable-neon --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-epoxy --libdir=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu --arch=arm64 --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-vout-drm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-librav1e --enable-shared
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
[x11grab @ 0x5555e1899a20] Cannot open display :0.0+100,200, error 1.
:0.0+100,200: Input/output error
```

I suspect x11grab is the problem, but have no idea what to use.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: **Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/**. Please delete this.

Answer (score -1):

From the ffmpeg manual:

---

Grab the X11 display with ffmpeg via

```
    ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0 /tmp/out.mpg
```

0.0 is display.screen number of your X11 server, same as the DISPLAY environment variable.

```
    ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size cif -framerate 25 -i :0.0+10,20 /tmp/out.mpg
```

0.0 is display.screen number of your X11 server, same as the DISPLAY environment variable. 10 is the x-offset and 20 the y-offset for the grabbing.

---

You need to do

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

and adjust the -i parameter accordingly.